# unexpected symbol near )

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

unexpected symbol near ')' on Line 10

I am new to programming and have followed everything in "LUA Tutorial 10b"

```
hook.Add( "PlayerSay", "CommandIdent", function( ply, text, team )
  if( text == "!hurt" ) then
    ply:SetHealth( ply:Health() - 25 )
    if( ply:Health() <= 0 ) then
      ply:Kill()
    end
    return "OUCH!"
  end

  if( string.sub( text, 1, 4, ) == "/ooc" ) then
    return "[OOC]" .. string.sub( text, 5 )
  end

end )
```

The script should translate "/ooc (message)" to "[OOC] (message)" when a user types it in game.

Comment: You have a `,` which you don't need after `string.sub( text, 1, 4` in line 10.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @char on the comments, apparently you've got an extra comma inline 10

```
if( string.sub( text, 1, 4, ) == "/ooc" ) then
```

It should be

```
if( string.sub( text, 1, 4 ) == "/ooc" ) then\
```

As stated in the [lua wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial).